# Type and Invocation of Swift's operators

Tags: swift

As per the official documentation, Swift's built-in operators are global functions defined with the `@infix` attribute.

As such, is the only way of invoking such a function to have it between two types for which the operator has been defined? Or is it possible to do something similar to e.g. `+(3,3)`?

What got me thinking is that this is a valid statement:

```
Array(1...10).reduce(0, +)
```

How, exactly, will the `+` be invoked in the above case? Is there a difference to this piece of code?

```
Array(1...10).reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, functions are just named closures and thus is `+`. So the two lines are pretty much identical. (The second one just wraps it in an additional invocation.)

You cannot do `+(3, 3)`, because an operator cannot be infix and prefix at the same time. However, you can after referencing it with another name:

```
let function: (Int, Int) -> Int = (+)
function(5, 6) // 11
```

(Writing `+` without putting it in the single-element tuple seems to confuse the compiler.)

Comment: That additional invocation from the `{$0 + $1}` will probably be stripped by the optimizer, so it's quite likely that both lines compile to the same code.